# type '_ControllerSubscription<String>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, stream, listener, bloc

I'm using bloc for getting the data entered to a textField and store it in a variable. I keep getting the error: "type '_ControllerSubscription' is not a subtype of type 'Stream'" after adding listener to the stream.

UI:

```
/****/
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var bloc = Bloc();

    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: size.height *.2 ,),
  StreamBuilder( stream: bloc.textStream,
     builder:    (context, snapshot ){
       return  Container(
          width: size.height * .5,
          height: size.height *.2,
          child: TextField(
 onChanged: bloc.changeText,
      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),),
 /****
   *****/
```

Bloc:

```
import 'dart:async';

class Bloc {

var _text='';
final  _textFieldController = StreamController<String>();

 get textStream => _textFieldController.stream
                  .listen( (value){_text = value;});    

 Function(String) get changeText => _textFieldController.sink.add;

  void dispose() {
   _textFieldController.close();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
get textStream => _textFieldController.stream
                  .listen( (value){_text = value;});
```

with

```
get textStream => _textFieldController.stream;
```

Comment: yes, there is no error will appear then, but how to store the value in the _text variable? (pardon me ..I'm new to streams and bloc)

Comment: Inside Bloc class you could do this

Bloc{
....
var listener;

Bloc(){
  listener = textStream.listen((val) {_text= val; })
}
...
}
https://pastebin.com/cDiSCTE4